# IE7 Ignores Conditional Statement

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, conditional-statements

I am finalizing the code for a company website where 90% of the users are browsing on IE.  My conditional statements have worked for all browsers with the exception of IE7.  I'm not sure why IE is ignoring the separate stylesheet I've created for IE browsing only.  Please review my code below.

Also this code here:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" charset="utf-8" />
```

...allows me to remove the compatibility mode in IE 7-9.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=EDGE" charset="utf-8" />
<tile>Company Site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" />
<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie8.css"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie7.css"><![endif]-->
</head>
```

Then the rest of my code appears to work and validate without issues. It seems as if IE7 is being ignored.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I'm noticing that your second code snippit doesn't have `IE=7` in the `X-UA-Compatible` bit -- was that intentional?

Comment: If you're using the X-UA-Compatible tag then I would ensure it downgrades everyone to IE7 and make IE7 work correctly. Then there's no reason for you to have extra style sheets and it takes out any further errors for future browsers.

Comment: @Deflect - I would love it if that was his answer!

Comment: Good to see you're using HTML5.

Comment: I can remove the IE 8 sheet and just use the if gte IE 8 statement and it should work for IE 8 & 9.  I will try that but IE 7 is ignoring whatever I throw at it and it's driving me NUTS!

Also it's not downgrading all of the IE browsers.  Some of the more recent browser upgrades are appearing like rounded corners, etc.

Comment: Maybe IE7 is having a problem with HTML5. I think there is a shim to fix that.

Comment: `content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE"` this is redundant: if you want Edge, then there's no point specifying the other versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I had to use the absolute link for the stylesheet instead of the relative link.  So using something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mywebsite.com/css/style.css">
```

instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Thanks for all of your help but it's always the small things with IE.

For the record, I also made sure I changed up how my header looked thanks to some great tips from you guys.  Here is the final header example as it stands now:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" charset="utf-8" />
<title>My Site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen">
<!--[if gte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysite.com/css/ie7.css"><![endif]-->
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `X-UA-Compatible` header is redundant. Its content should just be `IE=edge`, nothing more or less.

As for the stylesheets, you can test if the comment is being processed just by adding something visible, like `<script>alert("Hello!");</script>` (since you're in the `<head>`, you can't just put plain text in there).

If you do this and the alert shows up, then you probably have an issue in your CSS file. Either it's a 404, or you have specificity issues (as CrazyVipa suggested). We'll need more information to diagnose further if the above test is inconclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Nina,

You should check logs to see if it is being downloaded locally. It may seem that your CSS is not being applied, but possibly the CSS rules are being overwritten.

For example, if your standard CSS File has a:

```
#content-custom a {
color:#fff;
}
```

and your CSS conditional has:

```
.custom a {
color:#000;
}
```

Your font will show up with #fff. I haven't heard or seen any actual bugs relating to the conditional statements. The only issues I've noticed is human error. (Mis-type, Permissions, Local Environments, etc.) My assumption is the CSS file being overwritten. CSS Disabled? Invalid link?

Sorry to say this, but most likely, it is a typo on your part.

Comment: CrazyVipa I'd love to say that is the case but it isn't. On my test environment, compatibility mode in IE completely changed how the site appeared. When I uploaded it to the online server, I had to change my stylesheets again. I just learned that running IIS 7.5 all IE browsers on that particular server runs the site in compatibility mode. 

Anyhow, I made sure my divs are exactly the same on the both stylesheets. I'm stumped.

Comment: Try giving them a bigger priority. For example, on the normal stylesheet, "#custom-doc p"  Change to "html #custom-doc p" -- And are you positive the IE Machine is actually downloading the file?

Are you able to do a pastebin of the file(s) or something to give more information? I just ran a quick test here and all went well. Granted, we do not run IIS....

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it is not calling the file but probably the file is misplaced or something. You can take out the lines for the IE for now and just test the IE 7 file.